# Is it posible to configure Go Task runner to use fileextension yaml?

Tags: go, configuration, yaml, task, taskfile

Is there a posibility to configure Go Task runner (https://taskfile.dev/) to use files with file extension "yaml" instead of "yml"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task author here.

The only way to do it currently is by running:

```
task --taskfile=Taskfile.yaml
```

or

```
task -t Taskfile.yaml
```

That said, there's an [open issue](https://github.com/go-task/task/issues/183) and a [open PR](https://github.com/go-task/task/pull/184) about making `.yaml` extensions work automatically, so that will eventually work without the flag.

Comment: thank you, i've tested both commands and i got an `unknown flag: --taskfile`. I run version 2.5.2, do i need to update to the current version to do this?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to upgrade. `--taskfile` was introduced in v2.6.0 as noted by the [changelog](https://github.com/go-task/task/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Comment: I upgraded to Version 2.6.0 and it works perfect!
thank you